# Web Gardening in IIS 7.5 with WCF services

Tags: wcf, iis, web-garden

I have deployed WCF services in IIS 7.5. I want to create a web gardening in IIS, so I follow below steps to do that

On Application pool advance settings, I have set Maximum worker process=2.

My question is to do web gardening I need to change anything on machine.config or web.config file of WCF services?

If yes then what changes I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you need a web garden? Because it's a feature that is often misunderstood. [This](http://blogs.iis.net/chrisad/archive/2006/07/14/1342059.aspx) blog entry explains it quite well.

If you *really* need it, you don't need to configure anything in the config. The services themselves should not need to be aware of the fact they are executed from a garden or even from a farm.

Comment: thanks for replay.Actually my problem is ...we have windows 2008 R2 64 bit server with 2 processor in production.when I compiled WCF services on x64 bit mode from that day my CPU consumption is very high near about 100% all the time.So I am thinking that if by doing web gardening can i increase web service performance... other thing is that when I compiled WCF services  with "anycpu" mode and deployed in production then some times worker process get crashed so if process get crashed then application pool can used another worker  process. .. Please advice on this.

Comment: You should handle your original problem instead of rushing into new ones. Why don't you create a new question out of your problem description?

Answer (score 0):

You will need a web garden when you have a CPU with Many cores and you want to scale your application. Although there is no configuration which is specifically required there are just two things that you should be concerned.
1) There should be no static Variables in Your Service. Please do more R&D on that.
2) Your Services Concurrency Mode should be Multiple so that different threads which will be created should cater the service.